# Expand matrix and replace row and column names by key in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I'm running a linear mixed model with data from related individuals and multiple samples from the same individual. I have a kinship matrix with one kinship ID per individual. The kinship IDs differ from the assay IDs which the model is analyzing. I need to create a kinship matrix that has one row/column per assay ID rather than one row/column per kinship ID.

```
key = data.frame(assay_id = c("aid_1","aid_2","aid_3","aid_4","aid_5","aid_6"), kinship_id = c("kid_1","kid_2","kid_2","kid_3","kid_3","kid_4"))
key
start_kin = data.frame(kid_1 = c(1,0.25,0,0.5), kid_2= c(0.25,1,0,0.5), kid_3 = c(0,0,1,0.25), kid_4= c(0.5,0.5,0.25,1) )
rownames(start_kin) =c("kid_1","kid_2","kid_3","kid_4")
start_kin
intermediate_kin = start_kin
intermediate_kin$kid_2a = intermediate_kin$kid_2
intermediate_kin$kid_3a = intermediate_kin$kid_3
intermediate_kin["kid_2a",] = intermediate_kin["kid_2",]
intermediate_kin["kid_3a",] = intermediate_kin["kid_3",]
intermediate_kin
final_kin = intermediate_kin
rownames(final_kin) = c("aid_1","aid_2","aid_4","aid_6","aid_3","aid_5")
names(final_kin) = c("aid_1","aid_2","aid_4","aid_6","aid_3","aid_5")
final_kin
```

Comment: isn't that what you just did with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you wanted to do based on your description. Here is a code example based on my guess. Here, each kin has 3 assays.

```
kin <- letters[1:4]
assay <- 1:3
dat <- expand.grid(kin = kin, assay = assay)
dat <- apply(dat, 1, paste0, collapse = "-")
n <- length(dat)
m <- matrix(rep(0, n * n), nrow = n)
rownames(m) <- dat
colnames(m) <- dat
m

#     a-1 b-1 c-1 d-1 a-2 b-2 c-2 d-2 a-3 b-3 c-3 d-3
# a-1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# b-1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# c-1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# d-1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# a-2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# b-2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# c-2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# d-2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# a-3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# b-3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# c-3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# d-3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```